# If stomatopod crustaceans do not have myelination, why is their reaction so fast?

Tags: neuroscience, arthropod

As far as I understand, there are only two known ways of achieving fast nerve signal transmittance (and hence fast reaction time) in animals larger than ~10 cm: either myelination (as in vertebrates) or really thick neurons (like in cephalopods). However, stomatopods are both quite large and have devilishly fast reaction fitting their predatory lifestyle. They are definitely swifter and more "alive" than lobsters or crabs of the same size (who are all sleepy and slow). However, I have never seen it mentioned that stomatopods have myelination. In fact, [this page](https://www1.pbrc.hawaii.edu/%7Edanh/InvertebrateMyelin/) claims that mantis shrimp (stomatopoda) are not among the few crustaceans that have evolved myelination. Is there any research on how they manage to be so fast? Do they maybe have thick neurons like cephalopods? Or do they have another solution to nerve transmission?

Comment: Are you sure these animals have a fast *reaction time*? Or do they just *move quickly* or have a specialized high-velocity movement? These are not the same thing. Reaction time measures the time from some stimulus to the start of movement. It does not relate to the speed of the movement.